# Unresolved attribute reference 'is_selected'

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

Bit of a newbie so apologies if I'm missing something obvious.

Im trying to loop through some checkboxes to ascertain if they are selected or not and I am getting an unresolved attribute reference for is_selected.

It seems to not like the self_checkboxes locator in my example below:

```
class Checkboxes(BasePage):
    _checkboxes = {"by": By.CSS_SELECTOR, "value": 'input[type="checkbox"]'}
    _title_ = {"by": By.CSS_SELECTOR, "value": "#content > div > h3"}

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        self._visit("/checkboxes")
        assert self._is_displayed(self._title_)

    def is_checkbox_selected(self):
        self._wait_for_is_displayed(self._checkboxes, 5)
        print("\nWith .is_selected")
        for checkbox in self._checkboxes:
            print(checkbox.is_selected())
        assert self._checkboxes[-1].is_selected()
```

Any ideas why this is?

Comment: Your `for` loop is going to get the strings `by` and `value`, as that's what happens when you iterate over a python dict . . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`is_selected()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.is_selected) is a method available on a `WebElement` instance which is returned by the `driver.find_element_by_*()` methods. In your case, I would expect you to have something like this:

```
checkbox_element = self.driver.find_element(**self._checkboxes)
assert checkbox_element.is_selected()
```